# FilteredList.setPredicate throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, javafx

Hy guys,

I struggle with my JavaFX knowledge. Every time my ObservableList changes I would like to actualize my filter for the list which is displayed in a table (not shown here but the code reproduces the error). Unfortunately, I am having kind a strange problem.
The following code throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException whenever I change my property inside the ListChangeListener.

```
package com.tests.misterpresident;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class Tester extends Application {

    private static ObservableList<Person> myPersons;
    private static FilteredList<Person> filteredPersons;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myPersons = FXCollections.observableArrayList(person -> new Observable[]{person.duplicateProperty()});
        filteredPersons = new FilteredList<>(myPersons, p -> p.getDuplicate());

        myPersons.addListener((ListChangeListener<Person>) change ->
        {
            //check for duplicates
            while (change.next())
            {
                for(Person p1 : change.getAddedSubList())
                {
                    for(Person p2 : myPersons)
                    {
                        if(p1 == p2)
                            continue;
                        if(p1.getName().equals(p2.getName()))
                        {
                            p1.setDuplicate(true);
                            p2.setDuplicate(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Task t = new Task<Void>() {
            Random r = new Random();

            @Override
            protected Void call() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    int number = r.nextInt(10);
                    myPersons.add(new Person("Test" + number));
                }
                System.out.println("Finished");
                return null;
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(t);
        thread.run();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

    }

    static class Person{
        private String name;
        private BooleanProperty duplicate = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

        public Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            System.out.println("Created Person " + name);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public BooleanProperty duplicateProperty() {
            return duplicate;
        }

        public boolean getDuplicate()
        {
            return this.duplicate.get();
        }

        public void setDuplicate(boolean duplicate)
        {
            this.duplicate.setValue(duplicate);
        }
    }
}
```

Do you guys have a glue how to fix this problem or maybe you know an better solution.

Thank you!

**EDIT**
Backtrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList.addRemove(FilteredList.java:269)
    at javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList.sourceChanged(FilteredList.java:144)
    at javafx.collections.transformation.TransformationList.lambda$getListener$0(TransformationList.java:106)
    at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:524)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.access$200(ObservableListWrapper.java:45)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper$1$1.invalidated(ObservableListWrapper.java:75)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty.setValue(BooleanProperty.java:81)
    at com.tests.misterpresident.Tester$Person.setDuplicate(Tester.java:101)
    at com.tests.misterpresident.Tester.lambda$main$2(Tester.java:41)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.add(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:155)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at com.tests.misterpresident.Tester$1.call(Tester.java:56)
    at com.tests.misterpresident.Tester$1.call(Tester.java:49)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.tests.misterpresident.Tester.main(Tester.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
```

Comment: Is the exception being throws from `System.out.println("Object " + o.getProp1());`?

Comment: Nope it is not.

Comment: Then where is it being thrown?

Comment: Sry i forgot the backtace. I edited the post.

Comment: This is weird.  It's happening somewhere in the guts of JavaFX.

Comment: Any glue? I'm out of ideas! The my approach is basically ok?

Comment: Is `trackFilteredList` the same as `filteredObjects`?  Or is it a different FilteredList?

Comment: Sorry for that. I changed my code to a minimal failing testcase. Thank you guys

Comment: hmm .. you change the filteredList in a listener to its source - that might clash (and here does) because the filteredList is listening to the source as well. Didn't dig though, so take it with a grain of salt :) What are you trying to achieve (in your real world example)? why change the predicate on every change to the source list?

Comment: I'm having a TableView and a TextField. The TextField takes the filter for the data which is shown in my table. The data gets loaded in bulks with a Task in the background. Now I would like the user to see the data as early as possible but still it should not show any data where the filter does not apply for.

Comment: but why are you listening to the data to update the filter's predicate? I would expect you to listen to the textfield and update the predicate, I see no need to change the predicate when the source list is modified.

Comment: Ok thank you I got what you are telling me and it's rather working. Is there a method to invoke the filter? (A CheckboxMenuItem allows the user to display duplicates only, therefore I need to update the filter whenever a new item gets added -> now there might be a duplicate which hasn't been there before). Otherwise it just shows me one of the duplicates.

Comment: hmm ..  how do you filter the duplicates? That's not possible with a simple predicate anyway (not that I can think of, at a sunday morning after a saturday night <g>), so there's no need to update the filter.

Comment: haha, hope you had a good night <g> Happy Estern anyway! After adding an object, I run my duplicate algorithm (which has O(n*m) so it's rather fast for my pretty small n!). If there is a duplicate this algorithm sets the duplicate property of both elements to true.

Comment: I edited the post to my minimized code which throws the exception.

Comment: Thanks :) ohh ... same problem: you _must not_ change the list in any way while receiving a change! In this case it might appear that you get away with it as long as the list doesn't have an extractor nor the duplicate property is used anywhere outside (particularly not in the filteredList ...) .. which both apply. Simply don't change the list in the listener, it's not supported.

Comment: Ok thank you, this is exactly what I wanted to hear / needed to know. Now I perform the duplicate check after adding it to the list and it's working. Do you want to post the solution?